# How to create persistent bottom sheet that is always partially visible?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

How can I achieve the following effect on a flutter app.
I tried using persistent bottom sheet. But I'm not sure how to set the min and max height of the container. Also how to achieve the drag to expand effect?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W18eP.gif

Comment: Please provide us with the code which you have tried with so we can help you better.

Comment: “Bottom sheets in Flutter” by Joe Birch https://link.medium.com/xMuUnkAnuX  you may get a clear view of the bottom sheets. Do refer persistent bottom sheet you will find your answer